# Node promise-circuitbreaker - Returning a value from called function

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, circuit-breaker

I'm trying to use the promise-circuitbreaker node module.
I am able to pass a parameter to the called function, however, I am unable to have the called function return a value back.
Furthermore, I keep getting a timeout which I don't understand. I am obviously missing something, however I can't find any solution in the docs (http://pablolb.github.io/promise-circuitbreaker/)

I've made a very simple sample app to show my difficulties:

```
var CircuitBreaker = require('promise-circuitbreaker');
var TimeoutError = CircuitBreaker.TimeoutError;
var OpenCircuitError = CircuitBreaker.OpenCircuitError;


function testFcn(input, err) {
  console.log('Received param: ', input);
  //err('This is an error callback');

  return 'Value to return';
}

var cb = new CircuitBreaker(testFcn);

var circuitBreakerPromise = cb.exec('This param is passed to the function');

circuitBreakerPromise.then(function (response) {
  console.log('Never reach here:', response);
})
  .catch(TimeoutError, function (error) {
    console.log('Handle timeout here: ', error);
  })
  .catch(OpenCircuitError, function (error) {
    console.log('Handle open circuit error here');
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log('Handle any error here:', error);
  })
  .finally(function () {
    console.log('Finally always called');
    cb.stopEvents();
  });
```

The output I get from this is:

```
Received param:  This param is passed to the function
Handle timeout here:  { [TimeoutError: Timed out after 3000 ms] name: 'TimeoutError', message: 'Timed out after 3000 ms' }
Finally always called
```

In my case, I want a simple string to be returned. I don't want a timeout error.

If I uncomment the line //err('This is an error callback') in testFcn(), I get the following output:

```
Received param:  This param is passed to the function
Handle any error here: This is an error callback
Finally always called
```

So it appears that the 2nd parameter in the called function is for error handling.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.